# How to determine if refrigerated unopened cocktail sauce is still good?

Tags: condiments, ketchup

I found two unopened bottles of cocktail sauce in the back of the fridge. I have no idea how old they are.

One is Heinz "original". The label says "Best if used by date on cap", but there's nothing on the cap.

The other one is some generic brand in a very similar bottle, with "Best by 4 12 20" on the cap.

Is there a way of figuring out how old is the Heinz one?

Is the other one still ok, even if it's not "best" any more?

Comment: That one is more generic, and has a more generic answer

Comment: Also, that one doesn't cover the problem of bottle with no expiration date on it.